# Two GET in MVC C#

Tags: asp.net-web-api

```
public class EmployeesController : ApiController
    {
    public IEnumerable<Employee> GetAllEmployees()
    {
        return (new EmployeeData()).GetEmployeeRecords();
    }

    public Employee GetSingleEmployee(int id)
    {
        return (new EmployeeData()).GetSingleEmployeeRecord(id);
    }
    public void Delete(int id)
    {
        (new EmployeeData()).DeleteEmployeeRecord(id);
    }
}
```

This is what I have now. I'm trying to make the app call the first function with a get call api/employee and the second one with a get call api/employee/(an ID number) eg api/employee/75. The get call always goes to the first one. How do I solve this?

This is my routing:

```
 namespace EmployeeApp
 {
    public class RouteConfig
    {
          public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
          {
                    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
                    routes.MapRoute(
                        name: "Default",
                        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                        defaults: new { action = "Index", id=UrlParameter.Optional }
                    );
           }
     }
 }
```

Comment: what you are saying doesn't make sense.  How would a call to `api/employee/75` reach ***either*** of those routes?  the route definition you posted, as written, assumes `{controller}/{action}/{id}` === `controller===api`, `action===employee`, `id===75`.  neither of these actions are `employee`

Comment: I am kind of new to this. When I tracked where a get call with api/employee/75, it goes through the first method. Sorry if I am not clear enough. Ill try my best to be clear.

Comment: it **literally cannot**, unless there is more code that you aren't showing here.

Comment: please don't post code blocks in a comment; not only is it too small, it doesn't preserve formatting, and you aren't really showing anything new with that post anyway.

Comment: even with the new code posted, it is still **impossible** for a route of `api/employee/75` to reach the action of `GetAllEmployees()`.

Comment: OK. Thanks for the tip. Thats pretty much all I have for my code. I added that to the actual question. I added a breakpoint to the first method, and thats where it goes when I make a getJSON call from an html file with the url: api/employees/75

Comment: Hmm.. That is weird.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87793/discussion-between-claies-and-cyriac-domini-thundathil).

Comment: wrong place. sorry, removed :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a brief discussion in chat, we discovered that the issue here is that you have two different route configuration files, one for MVC and one for WebAPI.  While you could change the name of your actions to match the convention of the WebAPI route configuration (i.e. change `GetSingleEmployee` to `GetEmployeeById`), there is another way which would allow you to keep the actions named the same, and have more control over your desired routes.  My recommendation is to use the newer [Attribute Routing](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2) syntax.

First, change your configuration class like so:

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    // Web API routes
    config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

    // Other Web API configuration not shown.
}
```

next, change your class signature to define the routes through attributes:

```
[RoutePrefix("api/employee")]
public class EmployeesController : ApiController
{
    // http://example.com/api/employee/
    [Route("")]
    public IEnumerable<Employee> GetAllEmployees()
    {
        return (new EmployeeData()).GetEmployeeRecords();
    }

    // http://example.com/api/employee/75
    [Route("{id:int}"]
    public Employee GetSingleEmployee(int id)
    {
        return (new EmployeeData()).GetSingleEmployeeRecord(id);
    }

    // http://example.com/api/employee/Delete/75
    [Route("Delete/{id:int}")]
    public void Delete(int id)
    {
        (new EmployeeData()).DeleteEmployeeRecord(id);
    }
}
```

This controller now clearly shows it's routes, rather than the routes being defined somewhere else, or being defined by an obscure name matching convention.

Comment: try running `Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost` in the Package Manager Console just to ensure that the feature is enabled.

Comment: Package 'Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost.5.2.3' already exists in project 'EmployeeApp'

Comment: hmm, ok that's good, then it's already available, not sure why the 404 then, let me do a bit of quick searching on it

Comment: I played around with the mixing of WebAPI and MVC, the line for `config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();` has to be *before* any lines related to MVC routing, else the `/api/` route will be intercepted by MVC, and throw the 404.